# Whatsapp api to send a media

Tags: spring-boot, ionic-framework, whatsapi

Is it possible to use a whatsapp api to send messages (including files) without going through platforms like twilo because in its different platforms you must necessarily have a twilo account for each number who wants to send messages then that I want each person on my platform to be able to send messages independently
or even if there are platforms that offer the kind of service I want and that have a good API..
Any help will be appreciated thank you.

Note that I use SpringBoot and Ionic

I've seen twilo and nexomo but if anyone has any ideas I'm listening

Comment: Yes, of course. I think this is where unofficial whatsapp api with an elaborate white label system comes to your rescue. I don't want to advertise anyone, but if you search, you'll find some decent options.

Comment: okay thanks you